# Scraping outage data from PGE

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying to explore the correlation between power outage likelihood and income, and therefore attempts to scrape the power outage data from

https://pgealerts.alerts.pge.com/outagecenter/

When clicking the dot in the map, the time and the number of affected customers reveal. I want to collect the location(longitude/latitude). I start with duplicate and apply the tutorial in this video

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zesUhmT7Oz0&t=139s

but failed to see how to find the XHR/fetch that corresponding to the outage list (according to the steps in the video, I stuck in step 2).

I also have read previous attempts by [Simon](https://simonwillison.net/2019/Oct/10/pge-outages/), but did not see how he achieve that feat. Any suggestions about how to do this would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

For those interested, I eventually found an api in Simon's works. I don't know how he found it, but the api works for me.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).